# Can we export special characters using sqoop?

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I'm trying to export one of the tables from hive to MySQL using sqoop export. The hive table data contains the special characters.

## My hive "special_char" table data:

```
1   じゃあまた
2   どうぞ
```

## My Sqoop Command:

```
 sqoop export --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xxx/Sampledb --username abc --password xyz --table special_char --direct --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/sampledb.db/special_char --fields-terminated-by ' '
```

After using the above sqoop export command, the data is stored in the form of question marks (???) instead of actual message with special characters.

## MySql "special_char" table:

```
id  message
1    ?????
2    ???
```

Can anyone please help me out,in storing the special characters instead of question marks (???).

Comment: Did you try row level inserting same characters directly in SQL without Sqoop? If yes, is that working as expected?

Comment: Nope.. I'll try row level inserting same characters directly in SQL without Sqoop.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to insert the special characters into MYSQL directly

Answer (score 0):

Specify proper encoding and charset in the JDBC URL as below:

```
jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xxx/Sampledb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8

sqoop export --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xxx/Sampledb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8 --username abc --password xyz --table special_char --direct --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/sampledb.db/special_char --fields-terminated-by ' '
```

Please verify charset encoding for Japanese characters and use proper one.

Reference: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/198290/native-sqoop-export-from-hdfs-fails-for-unicode-ch.html

Comment: It is throwing the following error: Unrecognized argument: —username

Comment: I have used this :    sqoop export --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xxx/Sampledb --username abc --password xyz  --table special_char --direct --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/sampledb.db/special_char --fields-terminated-by ' '  --direct -- --useUnicode=true&amp --direct -- --characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: It is able to export the records but still it is storing the messages with "?????"

Comment: can you please try with UTF-16 encoding

Comment: And one more thing, by using " jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xxx/Sampledb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8 " in my sqoop command, it is throwing an error and it is unable to recognize the next attributes. Can you please suggest me regarding this ?